# CXF encoding embedded XML

Tags: java, xml, soap, cxf

I have a SOAP service which one of the methods accepts a String as a parameter. However, the expectation is that this String is XML.

When I call this service, CXF encodes the XML for me by default, like so:

```
&lt;ORM_O01>&lt;MSH>
```

Even though when I called it, I called it like so:

```
<ORM_O01><MSH>
```

Is there a way to turn this off? I would like CXF to just send what I've specified and not an encoded version.

I am using CXF 2.7.8 and JDK 1.7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look here: 

http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-jaxb-send-string-as-CData-tt5524523.html#a5530343

That should do it

Comment: @sasankad - no, not quite. I am not looking to wrap my content in CDATA, so this does not work. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is not the best way to do it, but it worked for me:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor< Message > {
    public MyClass () {
        super( Phase.PRE_STREAM );
        addAfter( AttachmentOutInterceptor.class.getName() );
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage( final Message message ) throws Fault {
        message.put( "disable.outputstream.optimization", Boolean.TRUE );
        final SimpleNsStreamWriter writer = (SimpleNsStreamWriter)StaxUtils.createXMLStreamWriter( message.getContent( OutputStream.class ) );
        message.setContent( XMLStreamWriter.class, new DelegatingXMLStreamWriter( writer ) {
            @Override
            public void writeCharacters( final String text ) throws XMLStreamException {
                System.out.println( "text -> " + text );
                writer.writeRaw( text );
            }
        } );
    }
```

Comment: This link had a similar example if it helps others as well [cxf jaxrs xml and cdata](http://www.codeyouneed.com/cxf-jaxrs-xml-and-cdata/) basically same as this answer.